# Generating a runnable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I'm trying to generate a runnable JAR file using Eclipse. In my bin folder, I have three folders all on the same level:

com
Properties
MiscFiles

In Eclipse, I have Properties and MiscFiles as Source Folders. When I go to export the JAR file as a runnable JAR, it includes the com folder but doesn't include the Properties and MiscFiles folder. I have to use an external program to manually add in those two folders. Is there a way to include these folders when exporting the JAR file?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507118/create-runnable-jar-with-properties-files-using-java-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.properties file.
And make sure that all the folders are added in it.

During jar generation it only considers the folders and files added into properties file.